# Heroku sync with salesforce

Tags: apex, heroku, sync, heroku-connect

Hi Can anyone suggests me, how can I put one button by which I can sync data from salesforce. I don't want to auto sync data from salesforce. But I need one button by which I can sync it whenevr I want.

Comment: You're going to need a lot more detail here. What kind of data, what kind of Heroku storage, what have you investigated/tried etc.

Comment: I just want to sync data of contact from salesforce. When data in salesforce is updated , heroku connect will automate sync with it but I need custom button from which, by clicking on it I can sync contact's data from salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

The are few JS frameworks that can help with that - in case offcourse you didn’t find any Heroku add on that can do it for u. 
Make sure you are aware of add ons like Heroku Connect which makes integration to SFDC quite simple.
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/salesforce_heroku_integration

For a button you can use something like example from here:
https://github.com/ccoenraets/forcejs

```
import {OAuth, DataService} from 'forcejs';

 let oauth = OAuth.createInstance();
  oauth.login().then(oauthResult =>     DataService.createInstance(oauthResult));

   let loadContacts = () => {
   let service = DataService.getInstance();
    service.query('select id, Name from contact LIMIT 50')
    .then(response => {
        let contacts = response.records;
        // do something with contacts
      });
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try CopyStorm from here: https://www.capstorm.com/backup/

You can pick whichever objects you want to sync, and save the data in all sorts of forms - we save it all in SQL Server.

You can do single syncs, or you can create a batch file and schedule it - it's up to you. It runs on Windows, Linux and Mac.
It has a 30 day trial (based on the SF Org Id, not the user)

Comment: Are you affiliated with this offering?

Comment: No, just a paying user